# Symbol not found error when I run a py2app application on OS X 10.4 Tiger

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am trying to bundle a python application, more specifically, a django site, as a self-contained `.app` container for Mac OS X. I am using `py2app` on OS X 10.6 to bundle the app.

The result works fine on OS X 10.5 or newer, but doesn't on my customer's OS X 10.4 Tiger. It fails with the following error:

```
/.../binary
  dyld: Symbol not found: ___stack_chk_guard
  Referenced from: /.../binary
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

1. What could I do to compile the binaries without references to that symbol, i.e., to cross-compile the application on OS X 10.6 for machines running 10.4?
2. How can I check whether the binary references that Symbol on OS X newer than Tiger? I do not have any test machine with OS X 10.4 here.

Comment: Mac OS X Lion was 10.7; Mac OS X 10.4 was Tiger.  Please clarify the title — I guess you need Tiger rather than Lion in the title.

Comment: Thank you. Cats confuse me.

Comment: I've not explored its inner workings or significance, but Perl builds so that `$Config{ld} = "env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 gcc"` (when I run the build; the Apple-provided `/usr/bin/perl` does not include this).  At least it is worth spending some time tracking this down.

Comment: In the ordinary course of events, you should encourage your customer to get a more modern version of the O/S.  Tiger was released in May 2004; the last update was in November 2007.  They've got their money's worth out of it; they should upgrade the hardware and the software.

Comment: The customer should set up a server running the django app with a proper Python installation rather than wanting an executable app for a single workspace. But you can't always convince customers about what is best.

Thank you for the Perl hint, I'll look into it!

Comment: FYI: As usual, Wikipedia has a good article on [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X) — though it appears the Mac has been dropped officially.  It's where I got the release date information from.  It doesn't cover building for old environments, so it isn't an answer to this question.

Comment: Try rebuilding py2exe with `-fno-stack-protector`.